# How do you keep a socket connection open indefinitely in C?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to implement a C socket server in Linux using the code from Beej's sockets guide, which is here:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/server.c

This works, and I've written a Windows client in C# to communicate with it. Once the client connects, I have it send a byte array to the server, the server reads it, then sends back a byte array. This works.

However, after this, if I have the client try to send another byte array, I get a Windows popup saying "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." Then I have to re-connect with the client again. I want to keep the connection open indefinitely, until the client sends a disconnect command, but despite reading through Beej's guide, I just don't seem to get it. I'm not even trying to implement the disconnect command at present, I'm just trying to keep the connection open until I close the server.

I've tried removing the close() calls in Beej's code:

```
while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
        ProcessRequest(new_fd); // this is not Beej's code, I've replaced his code here (which was a simple string send()) with a function call that does a read() call, processes some data, then sends back a byte array to the client using send().
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
}
```

But that just gets me an infinite loop of "socket accept: bad file descriptor" (I tried removing both the close(new_fd) lines, together and apart, and the close(sockfd) as well.
Can anyone more versed with C socket programming give me a hint where I should be looking? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the server disconnected? I am not sure that the message thrown from client indicates peer closure. Wireshark capture should confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the accept() problem is that sockfd isn't valid. You must have closed it somewhere. NB if you get such an error you shouldn't just keep retrying as though it hadn't happened.

The reason for the client problem is that you're only processing one request in ProcessRequest(), as its name suggests, and as you describe in your comment. Use a loop, reading requests until recv() returns zero or an error occurs.

Comment: I don't plan on downvoting, but I can see how people would say that this does not answer the question.

Comment: Possible, but then how the send/receive is working in the 1st iteration?

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that recv would return 0 if the client paused sending requests? The client won't be sending requests constantly, only when the user on the client end explicitly makes a request. Also, I thought it was already in a while loop?

Comment: @mrrrow No it wouldn't. recv() returns zero when the peer closes the connection. Not before. It's in a while loop accepting connections and processing a single response from each. He needs another one.

Comment: Thank you so much! A simple do/while (res>0) loop around ProcessRequest and changing void ProcessRequest to return an integer value into 'res' (int res;res = ProcessRequest(new_fd)) did the trick. That completely makes sense now. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

#### Cause

The reason client faces error is because of `close(new_fd)` either by the server-parent or server-child.

### Solution

At any point of time, a server may get two kind of events:

1. Connection request from a new client
2. Data from an existing client
   The server have to honor both of them. There are two (major) ways to handle this.

#### Solution Approach 1

Design the server as a concurrent server. In Beej's guide it is

```
7.2. select()—Synchronous I/O Multiplexing
```

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select
Since OP's approach is not this one, we do not explore it further.

#### Solution Approach 2

At server, `fork()` a process per client. This is the approach OP has taken and we explore here. Essentially, it is fine tuning the `ProcessRequest()` function in OP's code. Here is a sketch.

```
void ProcessRequest( int new_fd ) {
    char buffer[ N ];
    for( ; ; ) {     // infinite loop until client disconnects or some error

        int const recvLen = recv( new_fd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0 );
        if( recvLen == 0 ) { break; }    // client disconnected
        else if( recvLen == -1 ) { perror( "recv" ); break; }

        int const sendLen = send( new_fd, buffer, recvLen, 0 );
        if( sendLen == -1 ) { perror( "send" ); break; }
        // TODO if( sendLen < recvLen ) then send() in loop
    }
}
```

#### Note

I am sorry for having the half-baked solution four few hours. While I was editing the answer, I lost connectivity to stackoverflow.com which lasted for couple of hours.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I still get disconnected when I try to send data a 2nd time from the client to the server.

Comment: There's really no need to make it this complicated, since the server is already forking per-connection. `ProcessRequest` just needs a loop (per @EJP's answer).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: You are right, I was in middle of editing the answer, when I lost connectivity to SO for couple of hours. Please take a look at the updated answer and feel free to comment.